# React Native Fetch command returns JSON on debug builds, but not release builds

Tags: android, json, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I have an issue with react native where the debug build can successfully fetch JSON data using fetch from a server / API, but my release build does not. I have tried using useEffect as well as creating functions on onClick to retrieve data, but nothing seems to work. It either crashes and adb logcat says that phoneDetails or setPhoneDetails are undefined.

```
  let [phoneDetails, setPhoneDetails] = useState([]);
  let PhoneModel = 'VOG-L09';//Huawei P30 pro
  let saveJSON;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('API Call') //This gets JSON data from a server, specifically, the phone model and extra device info.
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setPhoneDetails(json));
//Also have tried:
      .then(json => (saveJSON = json));
//Then calling stringify on an alert to check if data is there.
  }, [PhoneModel]);
```

I have also tried using a simple async function using await similar to the code above but it doesn't work.

Comment: Add a .catch() to you API request. You'll find your error much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [phoneDetails, setPhoneDetails] = useState([]);
let PhoneModel = 'VOG-L09';
let saveJSON = null;

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
},[PhoneModel])

const fetchData = async () => {

   const response = await fetch(API);

   const json = await response.json();

   saveJSON = json

   setPhoneDetails(son)
}
```

try this and see. 
if it doesn't work, console log response and json and see what are you receiving.

Comment: Hi i tried this but it did not work for me in release mode.

I tried debugging, and when an alert was called, apparently the data was undefined before being evaluated. Do not know why this is an issue.